# Why does Python not have implicit conversions?

Tags: python, concatenation

Unlike in C++ or Java, whenever I have something like `print "Hello " + 1`, I get an error that it can't concatenate `str` and `int` objects. Why isn't this conversion done implicitly in Python?

Comment: And which one should be converted? Your `str` or your `int`? `Explicit is better than implicit`...

Comment: Well if I am `printing` all of them should be converted to `str` right ? or if I am assigning the concatenation to a str object then again all should be `str`..

Comment: All of them should be ultimately cast to `str` yes, but the behavior preceding the cast for printing is not so simple to deduce.  What if I say `print '4' + 2`?  Should I get `6` or `42`?  What about `print 4 + '2'`?

Comment: @Scharron Implicit conversion in C++ allows you to do the above and the result will just be a string "Hello1" that is printed out. Python only does implicit conversion with numerics (you can multiply a long by a double without recasting). It's just the way Python is.

Comment: @sr2222 yes that's a good point I guess

Comment: You can't assign to a string object. You can only assign to a name, which doesn't care what it references. In `a = '4' + 2`, you still have to figure out if the result is `42` or `6` before the assignment is made.

Comment: @scharron That is the whole point. Python would have to guess what to do. The language was created to explicitly dont't make quesses. See the [zen of python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) rule 2

Comment: @jomak: C++ doesn't implicitly convert int/... to stings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print "Hello", 1
```

The reason concatenation doesn't work is that string objects don't have any code in them to perform type conversion as part of their `__add__()` method. As for why, presumably Guido thought it would be a bad idea. The Zen of Python says "explicit is better than implicit."

You could write a string subclass that works this way, however:

```
class MagicStr(str):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return MagicStr(str(self) + str(other))
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return MagicStr(str(other) + str(self))
    __iadd__ = __add__
```

Of course, there's no way to get Python to use that class for string literals or for user input, so you end up having to convert strings constantly:

```
 MagicStr("Hello") + 1
```

At which point you might as well just write:

```
 "Hello" + str(1)
```

Comment: I wonder if you could monkeypatch String.__add__ instead of adding your own class, and get the desired effect.

Comment: No, you can't. You can't modify `str`.

Comment: @kindall That's not entirely true, there's the Forbidden Fruit package that can "curse" C originating objects with new attributes and methods.

Comment: So it says, but I have never actually used it succesfully.  :-)

Comment: @kindall You can re-assign the str..which only makes things confusing though,  making errors on calling `str` but still getting `type("dude")`: `str`...